# Calculation inside a variable in php

Tags: php, variables, integer

I am making a calculator application where a person can calculate things.
The input of the user wil be stored in a variable called input.
So for example:

```
$input = "3+10/2";
```

Is there anyway to calculate the answer?

Comment: Remove the quotes - you are treating it as a string, not an integer.

Comment: $input = ((3+10)/2);

Comment: @Qirel: That's because it is a string.  User input is pretty much always a string.

Comment: @David Not if you pass it as integers it won't.

Comment: @A-2-A: Changing the order of operations changes the result...

Comment: @Qirel: And how exactly would you propose that be done here?  I think you've misunderstood the question.

Comment: if you really want input as string then its basically a data structure question - in which operators will become parent nodes and numbers will be child nodes. You would need tree structure because equation can be complex consisting of brackets

Comment: Since it's user input, you can't just run it as PHP code by removing quotes as suggested but you can accomplish your goal.  Most dangerous method: use [`eval()`](http://php.net/eval).  Better method, parse it and then evaluate it.  See OP for link.

Comment: Take a look at https://gist.github.com/drawmyattention/13a34bf3ad5871a84c28